# Fresh Nova install, yet cannot delete newly created Users

Tags: laravel-nova

This is a new Laravel Nova install. I added a few test users, but I am unable to delete any. After confirming that I wish to delete the Resource, nothing happens. Refresh shows nothing was deleted.

The Laravel Log is empty.
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true 
I have installed Vue Devtools and compiled npm to dev mode, so I am seeing the Vue Console errors.

I haven't added any code and am running the latest - Laravel Framework 5.8.29, Nova 2.0.9, PHP 7.3.7

Attempting to Delete User with ID 4.

Expected: Resource is deleted and no errors.

Actual: Devtools Vue Console shows:

```
DELETE https://nova.local/nova-api/users?search=&filters=W10%3D&trashed=&viaResource=&viaResourceId=&viaRelationship=&resources[]=4 405

vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:6848 DELETE https://nova.local/nova-api/users?search=&filters=W10%3D&trashed=&viaResource=&viaResourceId=&viaRelationship=&resources[]=4 405
dispatchXhrRequest @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:6848
xhrAdapter @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:6699
dispatchRequest @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:7255
Promise.then (async)
request @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:7074
wrap @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:7495
request @ app.js?id=a16899bd00909d3799c4:52998
deleteResources @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:32864
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:96710
invoker @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:97035
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:96710
Vue.$emit @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:98730
deleteResource @ app.js?id=a16899bd00909d3799c4:9640
confirmDelete @ app.js?id=a16899bd00909d3799c4:7397
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:96710
invoker @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:97035
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:96710
Vue.$emit @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:98730
handleConfirm @ app.js?id=a16899bd00909d3799c4:9064
submit @ app.js?id=a16899bd00909d3799c4:39744
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:96710
invoker @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:97035
original._wrapper @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:102388
vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:95481 

[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "Error: Request failed with status code 405"

found in

---> <ResourceTable> at resources/js/components/ResourceTable.vue
       <LoadingView> at resources/js/components/LoadingView.vue
         <Card> at resources/js/components/Card.vue
           <LoadingView> at resources/js/components/LoadingView.vue
             <ResourceIndex> at resources/js/views/Index.vue
               <Root>
warn @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:95481
logError @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:96740
globalHandleError @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:96735
handleError @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:96695
(anonymous) @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:96712
Promise.catch (async)
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:96712
invoker @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:97035
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:96710
Vue.$emit @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:98730
deleteResource @ app.js?id=a16899bd00909d3799c4:9640
confirmDelete @ app.js?id=a16899bd00909d3799c4:7397
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:96710
invoker @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:97035
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:96710
Vue.$emit @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:98730
handleConfirm @ app.js?id=a16899bd00909d3799c4:9064
submit @ app.js?id=a16899bd00909d3799c4:39744
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:96710
invoker @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:97035
original._wrapper @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:102388
vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:96744 Error: Request failed with status code 405
    at createError (vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:7186)
    at settle (vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:7337)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:6747)
logError @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:96744
globalHandleError @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:96735
handleError @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:96695
(anonymous) @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:96712
Promise.catch (async)
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:96712
invoker @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:97035
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:96710
Vue.$emit @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:98730
deleteResource @ app.js?id=a16899bd00909d3799c4:9640
confirmDelete @ app.js?id=a16899bd00909d3799c4:7397
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:96710
invoker @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:97035
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:96710
Vue.$emit @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:98730
handleConfirm @ app.js?id=a16899bd00909d3799c4:9064
submit @ app.js?id=a16899bd00909d3799c4:39744
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:96710
invoker @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:97035
original._wrapper @ vendor.js?id=09758f7de86ec728ec5f:102388
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found my own solution.

IIS does not handle all Verbs by default, specifically, PUT and DELETE are not handled by default. I added DELETE to the Allowed verbs and - deletion!